# MapView crashes with setting to delegate

Tags: swift, mapkit, geocode

I am setting my map view to delegate yet so I can place an annotation callout on my pin, but I have a geocode that does something else only when a button is clicked. When I set the map view to delegate and I try to place a pin it crashes. How can I fix this?

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)
    let newCoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)

    //var newAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    //
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    //

    self.newAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    self.newAnotation.coordinate = newCoord
    newAnotation.title = "New Location"
    newAnotation.subtitle = "New Subtitle"
    //mapView.addAnnotation(newAnotation)

    self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.newAnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.newAnotation.coordinate
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
}
```

Screenshot of where it crashes,

[image]

Comment: What does the declaration of the `geocoder` look like? Is there any console output?

Comment: No there isn't. var geoCoder: CLGeocoder!

Comment: your geocoder is initialized before this method getting called?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting the following error log in your console output.And thats because  you have not initialise your `geoCoder` instance.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Declare it like this

```
var geoCoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
```